# Вставка иконок в список

Tags: html, jquery, css

- Нужно вставить иконки слева от содержимого `<li>`(иконки не обязательно разные).
- Желательно что бы `li:hover` выделял целый блок `<li>`  с иконкой.
- Ещё есть большая просьба помочь с `jquery`: как сделать так что бы изначально список был свернутым?
- И ещё не могу понять, как сделать так что бы когда выбирается один из элементов списка, свернуть весь список и на изначальном месте тэга `<span>` разместить содержимое выбранного `<li>`.

```js
$(function() {
  var contacts = ['Jenny Hess', 'Elliot Fu', 'Stevie Feliciano', 'Christian', 'Matt'];
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var span = document.createElement('span');

  for (var item in contacts) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerText = contacts[item];
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    ul.appendChild(span);
    div.appendChild(ul);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").addClass("wrapperDropdown");
  $("span").addClass("dropdown").text("Select Friend").prependTo("ul");
  $('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $("li").toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #95a5a6;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

ul li {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body >
    </body> 
    </html>
```